# При параллакс скроллинге панель с текстом подпрыгивает. Как это убрать?

Tags: html, jquery, css, parallax

[Вот код](http://jsfiddle.net/GXRQy/3/)

Сделайте резкий скролл вниз, увидите то явление, о котором я говорю. Концовка панели подпрыгивает. Как это можно убрать?

```js
$(window).on('scroll', function(){
 var frame = $('.frame').height();
 var scrolled = $(window).scrollTop();

  $('.frame').css({
   'top' : frame - scrolled
  })
})
```

```css
html {
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
}

.bg {
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 background-image: url('http://buzzfactory.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/Digital-Transformation-Enterprise.jpg');
 background-size: 100% 100%;
 z-index: 1;
}

.frame {
 height: 100.2%;
 width: 100%;
 background-color: #FFF;
 position: absolute;
 top: 100%;
 z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bg"></div>
 <div class="frame">
     <p>
            Сделайте резкий скролл вниз, увидите то явление, о котором я говорю. Концовка панели подпрыгивает. Как это можно убрать?Сделайте резкий скролл вниз, увидите то явление, о котором я говорю. Концовка панели подпрыгивает. Как это можно убрать?Сделайте резкий скролл вниз, увидите то явление, о котором я говорю. Концовка панели подпрыгивает. Как это можно убрать?Сделайте резкий скролл вниз, увидите то явление, о котором я говорю. Концовка панели подпрыгивает. Как это можно убрать?Сделайте резкий скролл вниз, увидите то явление, о котором я говорю. Концовка панели подпрыгивает. Как это можно убрать?Сделайте резкий скролл вниз, увидите то явление, о котором я говорю. Концовка панели подпрыгивает. Как это можно убрать?</p>
 </div>
```

Comment: никто не сталкивался с этим?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Неправильно считаете сдвиг. У вас меняется высота документа в процессе скроллинга. Соответственно меняется scrollTop, который влияет на top блока, который меняет высоту документа, который....

```
var frame = $('.frame').height();
$(window).on('scroll', function () {
    var scrolled = $(document).scrollTop();

    $('.frame').css({
        'top': frame - scrolled / 2
    })
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9Kuey/

ЗЫ Тут тоже могут быть скачки (на 1px) из-за ошибки округления после деления на 2, думаю, сами отловите.
ЗЗЫ `height:100.2%` - это чтоб вообще скучно не было, да.

Comment: Спасибо огромное!